# Template and Place holders algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, templates, placeholder

First a quick definition :)

- **Template** - A string which may contain placeholders (example:"hello [name]")
- **Placeholder** - A substring whitin square brackets (example: "name" in "hello [name]:).
- **Properties map** - A valid object with strings as values

I need to write a code that replace placeholders (along with brackets) with the matching values in the properties map.

example:
for the following properties map:

```
{
    "name":"world",
    "my":"beautiful",
    "a":"[b]",
    "b":"c",
    "c":"my"
}
```

Expected results:

- "hello name" -> "hello name"
- "hello [name]" -> "hello world"
- "[b]" -> "c"
- "[a]" -> "c" (because [a]->[b]->[c])
- "[[b]]" -> "my" (because [[b]]->[c]->my)
- "hello [my] [name]" -> "hello beautiful world"

Comment: What happens if there's a loop, like a -> [b] and b -> [a]?  Also, are all decisions forced (that is, no key maps to more than one value?)

Comment: sure, ignore the loops. consider the map object to valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var map = {
    "name":"world",
    "my":"beautiful",
    "a":"[b]",
    "b":"c",
    "c":"my"
};

var str = "hello [my] [name] [[b]]";

do {
    var strBeforeReplace = str;
    for (var k in map) {
        if (!map.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue;
        var needle = "[" + k + "]";
        str = str.replace(needle, map[k]);
    }
    var strChanged = str !== strBeforeReplace;
} while (strChanged);

document.write(str); //hello beautiful world my
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @chris is excellent, I just want to provide an alternative solution using regular expressions that works "the other way round", i.e., not by looking for occurrences of the "placeholder versions" of all items in the properties map, but by repeatedly looking for occurrences of the placeholder itself, and substituting it with the corresponding value from the property map. This has two advantages:

1. If the property map grows very large, this solution should have
   better performance (still to be benchmarked though).
2. The placeholder and the way substitutions work can easily be modified by adjusting the regular expression and the substitution function (might not be an issue here).

The downside is, of course, that the code is a little more complex (partly due to the fact that JavaScript lacks a nice way of substituting regular expression matches using custom functions, so that's what `substituteRegExp` is for):

```
function substituteRegExp(string, regexp, f) {
    // substitute all matches of regexp in string with the value
    // returned by f given a match and the corresponding group values
    var found;
    var lastIndex = 0;
    var result = "";
    while (found = regexp.exec(string)) {
        var subst = f.apply(this, found);
        result += string.slice(lastIndex, found.index) + subst;
        lastIndex = found.index + found[0].length;
    }
    result += string.slice(lastIndex);
    return result;
}

function templateReplace(string, values) {
    // repeatedly substitute [key] placeholders in string by values[key]
    var placeholder = /\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]/g;
    while (true) {
        var newString = substituteRegExp(string, placeholder, function(match, key) {
            return values[key];
        });
        if (newString == string)
            break;
        string = newString;
    }
    return string;
}

alert(templateReplace("hello [[b]] [my] [name]", {
    "name":"world",
    "my":"beautiful",
    "a":"[b]",
    "b":"c",
    "c":"my"
})); // -> "hello my beautiful world"
```

**Update**: I did some little profiling to compare the two solutions (jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/n8Fyv/1/, I also used Firebug). While @chris' solution is faster for small strings (no need for parsing the regular expression etc), this solution performs a lot better for large strings (in the order of thousands of characters). I did not compare for different sizes of the property map, but expect even bigger differences there.

In theory, this solution has runtime O(*k*  *n*) where *k* is the depth of nesting of placeholders and *n* is the length of the string (assuming dictionary/hash lookups need constant time), while @chris' solution is O(*k*  *n*  *m*) where *m* is the number of items in the property map. All of this is only relevant for large inputs, of course.

Comment: Thank you, that is really elaborating!

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with .NET's `String.Format`, then you should take a look at [this JavaScript implementation](https://github.com/scottrippey/JavaScript-Utilities/blob/master/String.Format.js).  It supports number formatting too, just like `String.Format`.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
var result = String.Format("Hello {my} {name}", map);
```

However, it would require some modification to do recursive templates.